# How would I use the largest expected effect size to determine a prior?

Tags: bayesian, prior, bayes-factors

I have a simple experiment in which ~30 people responded to 100 words, half of which were of Type A and half of which were of Type B. I am using a mixed effects linear regression to predict reaction time differences between words of Type A and Type B. I am also using a ME logistic regression to predict accuracy differences. These models are being fit using Bayesian parameter estimation.

Ultimately I am interested in determining the probability that the null hypothesis is true given the data. I am going to do this using Bayes Factors to compare models with and without the parameter of interest (i.e., word type).

Based on the literature, the largest possible mean difference I would expect between Type A and Type B is 100 ms. The effect size that I'd expect to be **most** likely is around 30 ms. I should be clear that these are both what I would expect *if* there is an effect. I think the most likely expectation is to find no effect at all.

I am curious how to now turn this into a prior. The various advice I have found so far is to:

- use a normal distribution centred at zero with a standard deviation equal half of the maximum expected effect size
- use a normal distribution centred at zero with a standard deviation equal to the expected effect size
- set a uniform distribution across all possible effect sizes

I'm wondering if there are other rules of thumb in setting up the prior based on a maximum possible effect size and/or expected effect size? Is it common practice to centre the prior at zero? Note that this is all for the purpose of computing a Bayes Factor for the effect of word type.

Comment: **Why** do you wish to use a Bayesian technique? What do you believe is the advantage?

Comment: To be able to comment on the probability of the null hypothesis being true given the data.

Comment: Why do you wish to make that comment? How are you gonna use it?

Comment: To publish a paper on the limits of a given phenomenon/effect.

Comment: As an experimental scientist, to publish a paper it is sufficient to provide the results along with a maximum likelihood estimate and confidence interval. There is no need to 'spoil' this with a (subjective) prior if the posterior that you obtain from it has no practical use. No data is gonna give (on it's own) the probability of the null hypothesis or the limits of an effect. The data is only working as making certain values more or less likely than before (and that, this pure likelihood, is what you wish to convey in your publication).

Comment: Still there might be reasons to use a Bayesian method, also for your article, but I believe it should be led by good reasons. Especially it should be made more explicit/direct/clear what the goal is to have the posterior. What could one do with it. Why would somebody not just use the prior and not at all do the specific additional experimental research? What is new about your experiment/data? Why express your result using old data/information/prior?

Comment: Note, I do not want to talk you out of using a Bayesian technique. However, the consideration what you want to do with the posterior probability estimate clarifies what to do with the choice of prior probability estimate.

Comment: Thanks for the input! My hope is to use the posterior to compute the Bayes Factor in favour of the null hypothesis.

Comment: @Dave I believe the question is about the broader scientific goal, which should motivate your choice of methods.

Comment: @Dave, you mention that *"the most likely expectation is to find no effect at all"*. Can you quantify this?

Comment: It's hard to mentally go back in time. But I would have said we had about a 50% chance of not finding an effect.

Comment: It sound like you could go for a mixture of two priors. A 50% of the time the probable mean reaction time is centered around 0 with a tiny dispersion (or a delta function if you like). And a 50% of the time with the mode around 30ms and a wide dispersion. How is your problem a logistic regression?  The reaction time difference has a minimum and maximum? If you assume a gaussian distribution for observed reaction time differences then calculations would be easier. Do you have an idea about the distribution of the residual/error term?

Answer (score 2):

A good way to set priors is using [prior predictive checks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.01449) - basically you simulate new datasets from your model. If the simulated datasets are unrealistic in any way, it means your priors have problems.

Prior predictive checks have the advantage that they take complete structure of the model into account. If you however have only one effect in the model or have other reasons to believe you can set the prior independently for each parameter, and you have minimal bound $c_-$ and maximal bound $c_+$ than a good way is to choose a family and then find such parameters for the family that $P(\beta < c_-) = P(\beta > c_+) = \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is small, but not extremely small ($0.05$ tends to work nice).

Stan wiki has some more considerations:
https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations

Note that it is IMHO wrong to a-priori exclude effects in the opposite direction than expected.

Also, Bayes factors tend to be very sensitive to the parts of priors that don't matter for normal inference (e.g. choosing $N(0,100)$ vs. $N(0,1000)$ when the ML estimate is 0.5).